# How can I take the first input of ...?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyeval

I want to create a function where the first input of `create_df` gets turned into the number 1 using tidyeval. Here it should be only the `cyl` column.

How do I pull the first "input" of `...`?

```r
  library(dplyr, quietly = T)

create_df <- function(...){
  
  var <- enquos(...)
  first <- as_label(quos(...))
  
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(!!!var) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(mpg)) %>% 
    mutate(!!first := 1)
}

create_df(cyl, am)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl    am  mean `<quos>`
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     4     0  22.9        1
#> 2     4     1  28.1        1
#> 3     6     0  19.1        1
#> 4     6     1  20.6        1
#> 5     8     0  15.0        1
#> 6     8     1  15.4        1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pull the first variable out of the dots by simply taking the first element out of `vars` (with credit to Lionel Henry for pointing this out).

```
create_df <- function(...){
  
  var <- enquos(...)
  first <- as_label(var[[1]])
  
  mtcars %>% 
    group_by(!!!var) %>% 
    summarise(mean = mean(mpg)) %>% 
    mutate(!!first := 1)
}

create_df(cyl, am)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'cyl' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [1]
#>     cyl    am  mean
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     0  22.9
#> 2     1     1  28.1
#> 3     1     0  19.1
#> 4     1     1  20.6
#> 5     1     0  15.0
#> 6     1     1  15.4
```

Comment: `list2()` doesn't do anything here. And `quos(...)` is exactly the same as `enquos(...)` (the behaviour is the same for dots, it only differs for other arguments). So you can simplify your code with: `first <- as_label(var[[1]])`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out @LionelHenry - I have updated, with credit to your good self!